# Modify Image Url Value with Vue Js in a Loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple Loop with conditionals. I want to modify the full url to a version of the image with 60x60 pixels.

Full image url : www.example.com/img/full-image-001.jpg .

Modified image url that I need : www.example.com/img/full-image-001-60x60.jpg .

```
<template v-else-if="column === 'product_img'">
     <img :src="replaceLink.columnValue" alt="" height="60" width="60">
</template>
```

Method function:

```
methods : {
    replaceLink (record) { //logic 
    }
}
```

---

EDIT : 
Is this the proper way ?

```
methods: {
    replaceLink (record) {
        let res = record.replace(".jpg", "-60x60.jpg");
        console.log(res);
    }
},
```

Comment: What is in the `record` argument? Please post a workable example

Comment: The record is the var that equals to 'www.example.com/img/full-image-001.jpg'

Comment: I did this and its working, but I'm new to vue and i dont know if it is the proper way `.replaceLink (record) {
    let res = record.replace(".jpg", "-30x30.jpg");
    console.log(res);
} `

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Better solution is to create filter and use it on your images.

Instead fo **methods** object create **filters** object with replace function:

```
filters: {
  replaceLink: function(value) {
    if (!value) return '';
    return value.replace('.jpg', '-60x60.jpg');
  }
}
```

And now in your HTML you can use it like this:

```
<img :src="source | replaceLink" />
```

*You should have **source** in your component data or you will get an error. This source should be image url*

Comment: Can you explain what makes this version "better"?

Comment: This is exact case what filters are made for. You can define this filter in global Vue instance and you can use it in every component. They are flexible and easy to reuse.

Comment: Right, but there isn't any reason that this is "better" than a method

Comment: I don't know others, but for me if code can be reused, it's already a better solution that rewrite it in every component.